# Kodak Android TV Not able to connect via ADB on WiFi

Tags: adb, android-tv

Am trying to change the Homescreen of Kodak Android TV by follow the steps [Completely change home screen on Android TV](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/162935/completely-change-home-screen-on-android-tv)

The TV and Laptop are connected on same WiFi. Able to ping the TV's IP.
But when am trying to connect the TV via ADB connect, it's showing below error.

*C:\Intel\ADB>adb connect 192.168.1.105
cannot connect to 192.168.1.105:5555: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (10061)*

Kodak TV Android version 9, Kernel version 4.9.125, Build PTT1.181130001 release keys.

In TV, I've already enabled developer options, USB Debugging.

Am using platform tools adb version (Not Android studio). Is there anyway to connect to TV without using USB Cable?

Answer (score 1):

`adb connect` can only be executed for an device that has adb over wifi activated (usually this is reset on every reboot). The common way is to connect the device via USB and execute `adb tcpip 5555`. I am not sure about Android TV devices, if they have adb over Wifi activated by default. You should use a port scanner and check if there is any TCP port open on your Android TV box. May be adb is not running on port 5555 on your device.

Without that command adb will work only via USB. Therefore the only chance I see would be an app that can enable adb wireless mode, however if I remember correctly this requires root permissions if executed from within an app.

Comment: So, I must connect the TV with my Laptop via USB A cable and enable TCP before connecting with WiFi. I'll try that.

Comment: I used USB Male to USB Male cable and it works fine. adb connect is a no go for my device.

Comment: This worked for me. Connected via USB, then prompted `adb tcpip 5555` and then connected to the device via wifi: `adb connect 192.168.1.155`